# Why does it show terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error' what(): basic_string::_S_construct null not valid

Tags: c++

At first, I thought there is an error when I was using the while loop so I've tried using for loop but it still displays the same error. I have tried to look up the reason why this error happened but I am still unable to figure out which line in these codes caused the error.

```
int main()
{
    ifstream patientData;
    string name;
    int count = 0;
    patientData.open("PatientList.txt");

    string patient_name[NUM_PATIENTS] = {0};
    double ward[NUM_PATIENTS]         = {0};
    double surgery[NUM_PATIENTS]      = {0};
    double medication[NUM_PATIENTS]   = {0};
    double service[NUM_PATIENTS]      = {0};
    double totalCharge[NUM_PATIENTS]  = {0};

    while(count < NUM_PATIENTS)
    {
        getline(patientData, patient_name[count], '\t');        
        patientData >> patient_name[count];
        patientData >> surgery[count];
        patientData >> medication[count];
        patientData >> service[count];
        patientData >> totalCharge[count];
        count++;
    }

    patientData.close();
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize in advance if this sounds like a stupid question.
Currently, I'm following the guide from a textbook named "Starting Out with C++ From Control Structures through Objects Ninth Edition by Tony Gaddis"
Can someone help me?

Comment: Regarding *"I am still unable to figure out which line in these codes caused the error"* now would be a great time to learn how to use a debugger. You can put breakpoints and step through the code line by line as it is executing, and look at the values of your variables to identify which parts are executing properly or incorrectly.

Comment: I suspect that initializing `string patient_name[NUM_PATIENTS]` calls `std::string::string(const char*)` (casting `0` to `(const char*)0`) but this constructor may not be called with a null pointer. You may use a debugger (as suggested by @CoryKramer) to prove me right or wrong.

Comment: Btw. `std::string` has a default constructor. Hence, `string patient_name[NUM_PATIENTS];` should be fine providing you an array of empty strings as intended.

Comment: *I'm following the guide from a textbook* -- Did the textbook show setting a `std::string` array to `0`?  I bet it didn't.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat thank you for pointing that out, I will re-check that part again

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yes you are correct it didn't, that was my mistake

Comment: I made an [MCVE on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a69608f5a59628e7) to prove me right. However, the [answer of Hajo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70804671/7478597) is sufficient and worth to be accepted. I've nothing of worth to add. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: You are trying to initialize your arrays with 0, which is a nullptr. So you are actually trying to initialize your first string in the array with a nullptr.

Let's examine

```
string patient_name[NUM_PATIENTS] = { 0 };
```

- It defines an old style C array of `NUM_PATIENT` strings.
- It initializes this array with `{ 0 }`.
- ... which means, the first string get's initalized with `0`, the rest of the strings get default-initialized.
- ... which means, the first string in the array is initialized thus: `string(0)`, which is similar to `string(nullptr)` - which probably leads to your exception `string::_S_construct null not valid`

---

Actually all your attempts at initalizing are wrong.

You don't need to write `= {0}` for the `patient_name[NUM_PATIENT]` array *at* *all*, because the strings in this array are "default-initialized". They know how initialize themselves to an empty string.
`string patient_name[NUM_PATIENT];` is enough.

But your other arrays don't get properly initialized at all. `= {0}` will initialize *the* *first* element of your vector. The remaining elements are "default" initialized (for classes) or not initialized at all (for doubles).

Don't use `patient_name[NUM_PATIENT]` at all. Get a better textbook. This is an old-style C array. Use `std::vector` (best) or `std::array` (better).

Much better would be this:

```
   std::vector<string> patient_names;
   std::vector<double> medication...

   for (size_t i=0; i<NUM_PATIENT; ++i) {
      string next_patient;
      getline(patients, next_patient);
      patient_names.emplace_back(next_patient);
...
```

or, to stick close to the text book:

```
   std::vector<string> patient_name(NUM_PATIENTS);
...
   while (count<NUM_PATIENTS) {
      getline(patients, patient_name[count]);
```

Comment: I believe, this is your fault: _`= {0}` will initialize the first element of your vector._ These are C arrays, and initializer `{ 0 }` is the specific way to fill it with 0s (all elements).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I see, thank you for the new knowledge